# CORS Post in IE9 fails

Tags: asp.net-web-api, internet-explorer-9, http-post, cors

So I'm creating an application which uses CORS to communicate with a .NET MVC Sidecar project. Everything works great except for in IE9, where POST requests fail. I have a [library](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest) which allows the GETs to work, but the POST requests are still having issues. It seems that IE9 strips out the `contentType` header. The server ends up interpreting this as `appplication/octet-stream`, as opposed to `text/plain` which is what I understand it's actually getting set by.

Inside of my WebAPIConfig.cs, I have the following function (called by `Register`):

```
private static void RegisterFormatters(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // enable browser viewing + jsonp
        config.Formatters.Add(new BrowserJsonFormatter());
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(new BrowserJsonFormatter()));

        // prettify json: indented + camel case
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        // Tell the formatter to accept text/plain
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
        // When we use CORS on IE9, it strips off the content type. The server assigns it application/octet-stream
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
    }
```

However, Fiddler is still telling me that the requests don't have a contentType, and that the server can't handle a contentType of `application/octet-stream`.

Has anyone gotten this working?

Comment: What do the F12 tools tell you? The same? I never trust info from anything other than IE9 tools, and then you still can't trust them to tell you everything. If you need a VM go to http://modern.ie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by creating my own `MediaTypeFormatter` that worked with `application/octet-stream`. (My server was not accepting the calls because I hadn't done an IIS Reset (duh), but it still wasn't correctly parsing the objects.

Here's the formatter I ended up using.

```
public class OctetStreamMediaTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    public OctetStreamMediaTypeFormatter()
    {
        // We only support octet-stream
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        var task = new Task<object>(() =>
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(readStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                // The data is passed as somethign identical to a query string (but not in the query string)
                var dic = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(reader.ReadToEnd());
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k =>
                {
                    if (k.EndsWith("[]"))
                    {
                        return k.Substring(0, k.IndexOf("[]", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return k;
                    }
                }, k =>
                {
                    var val = dic[k];
                    // We need to speciallly handle arrays
                    if (k.EndsWith("[]"))
                    {
                        // parse into separate values;
                        var values = val.Split(',');
                        val = values.Aggregate("[", (current, value) => current + ("'" + value + "',"));
                        if (val.EndsWith(","))
                        {
                            val = val.Substring(0, val.Length - 1);
                        }
                        val += "]";
                    }
                    return val;
                }));
                // It still puts it in as a string, which is not what we want, so we need to remove the quotes
                json = json.Replace("\"[", "[").Replace("]\"", "]");
                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type);
                return obj;
            }
        });

        task.Start();

        return task;
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://caniuse.com/cors 
CORS is supported by the following browsers: Firefox 3.5+, Internet Explorer 10+, Google Chrome 4.0+, Safari 4.0+,
Opera 12.0+, and Opera Mobile 12.0+

XDomainRequest  might be able to help you(IE8+ )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>XDR</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
xdr.open("get", "http://localhost:6504/api/resourcename/1");
xdr.onload=function()
{
alert(xdr.responseText);
}
xdr.send();
</script>
```

Comment: The library I'm using already handles this for me. The get requests are now happening just fine.